# Dynamically update CSS variable in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to make dynamic gradient transition, where I have to change one specific variable from the gradient, but I just can't access the variable. I read the docs but still don't know how.
Here is the gradient code

```css
background: radial-gradient(circle, hsla(274, 75%, 37%, 1) 0%, hsla(280, 100%, 80%, 1) 60%);
```

I am wanting to update the last "60%" value dynamically.

The variable is forced to be percent variable but my variable is float which makes it worse. Is there any way to acces the variable and convert my float variable to percent in vue js?
I appreciate any help :)

Comment: JavaScript does not define different types of numbers.  They're all stored as double precision floating point numbers.  also, CSS takes numbers as strings so the exact number format shouldn't really matter since all you need to do is add `+ '%'` to convert to "percent" string.  I've answered the rest of your question but if there's more help you need with the number formatting then give an example of the exact format of a number you're given and what format you want to convert it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Vue 3 with [v-bind() in CSS](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#v-bind-in-css)

`v-bind()` can be used to bind a reactive variable or computed property to a CSS property.  Updating the CSS value is then as easy as updating the reactive variable.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="box" />
    <input v-model="lastPercent" type="range" min="1" max="100" />
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      lastPercent: 60
    }
  },
  computed: {
    gradient() {
      return `radial-gradient(circle, hsla(274, 75%, 37%, 1) 0%, hsla(280, 100%, 80%, 1) ${this.lastPercent}%`
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

```css
<style>
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: v-bind(gradient);
}
</style>
```

[Playground example](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNpNUFFugzAMvYqFVqmVaEnXba0Ym7Qb7AB8NCUZRAshCoZRVdx9zjIoUuQ8+704z75FH9bu+k5GaZShrK3mKN9zA5AJ1f+BAKHQvG3f8ujSDHkEyUQpYzuEfls3QmqiSYWf0hXSIMnwaiUVHTelpLRWhrK9R3zwiLG5V5aED7NkYYPStnDKImE52MYhCPnFO41w848ER77eBAzgJHbOTBnAwksKLyyUR3+NsY9FU5N5KdLpSem4UKS+t5ybnj3F9XaWFMoVWsZQtZqvH49PMRyfVzEcjhT2G2B0BerEqMB8fvKBuIcbVqrdLeyNq/PSXW7oZMk8ul8DXrXfyI72H8z9KIFVCgfG7PDqC5VUZUWT3isXXnyXrukMjdhvL8qI9eR/Q4LwyX/jaPwFOAuniQ==)

### Vue 2 with [var()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var)

Vue 2 is slightly more involved.  You need to bind the computed variable to the element and *also* assign the variable in the styling with `var()`. The syntax of `var()` requires you precede the variable name with two hyphens, e.g. `--variableName`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="box" :style="boxStyle" />
    <input v-model="lastPercent" type="range" min="1" max="100" />
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      lastPercent: 60
    };
  },
  computed: {
    boxStyle() {
      return {
        '--gradient': `radial-gradient(circle, hsla(274, 75%, 37%, 1) 0%, hsla(280, 100%, 80%, 1) ${this.lastPercent}%`
      };
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

```css
<style>
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: var(--gradient);
}
</style>
```

[codepen example](https://codepen.io/yoduh/pen/poQgRQw)